# Does instantiating multiple mysqli objects in a single PHP script get optimized?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a base model class that wraps mysqli. When I instantiate multiple models each one calls `new mysqli()`. If the parameters passed to `mysqli()` are the same will it be optimized for me and only use one connection?

I guess another way to ask this is...is this:

```
$mysqli1 = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
$mysqli2 = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
$mysqli3 = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

more or less equivalent to this:

```
$mysqli1 = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
$mysqli2 = $mysqli1;
$mysqli3 = $mysqli1;
```

Edit:
I remember reading somewhere that it does return a copy if you're already connected but I can't find it now.

Comment: Try it and see if the variables reference the same objects - My guess is probably not though because the docs specifically state that the constructor will "Open a **new** connection to the MySQL server"

Comment: If I tried it I wouldn't know how to determine if it's being optimized for me.

Comment: @Ryan The way to test is to `var_dump($mysqli1); var_dump($mysqli2); ...`  You'll see a different object reference # for each one. (they won't be optimized down, you'll get a pile of different connection resources)

Comment: are you saying it's not negligible to connect more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will open a new connection to the database. Every time you create an instance of mysqli class, even if with the same parameters, it will create a new instance.